# Mutable struct vs. class?

Tags: c#, class, memory, struct, mutable

I'm unsure about whether to use a mutable struct or a mutable class.
My program stores an array with a lot of objects.
I've noticed that using a class doubles the amount of memory needed. However, I want the objects to be mutable, and I've been told that using mutable structs is evil.
This is what my type looks like:

```
struct /* or class */ Block
{
    public byte ID;
    public bool HasMetaData; // not sure whether HasMetaData == false or
                             // MetaData == null is faster, might remove this
    public BlockMetaData MetaData; // BlockMetaData is always a class reference
}
```

Allocating a large amount of objects like this (notice that both codes below are run 81 times):

```
// struct
Block[,,] blocks = new Block[16, 256, 16];
```

uses about 35 MiB of memory, whilst doing it like this:

```
// class
Block[,,] blocks = new Block[16, 256, 16];
for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++)
for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
    blocks[x, y, z] = new Block();
```

uses about 100 MiB of ram.

So to conclude, my question is as follows:

Should I use a struct or a class for my Block type? Instances should be mutable and store a few values plus one object reference.

Comment: Have you considered using an immutable struct and just swap the entire value? Think: how DateTime.AddDays(...) returns a new/different DateTime, but a DateTime never changes

Comment: a) why should they be mutable? That's not evident here. b) 100 MB is not very much.

Comment: No point storing HasMetaData btw; that is costing you (it will be aligned etc), and a null check is trivial - no worse than a bool check

Comment: Marc Gravell: Thanks, I haven't thought of that yet. I will consider it. Henk Holterman: Whilst the program is running, either ID or sometimes MetaData will change. Also, there is chance I will be having a lot more than 16*16*256 values. Marc Gravell: Thanks, I will remove HasMetaData.

Comment: Marc and Henk are right. First off, if you are worried about memory usage then **eliminate all possible redundancy**. Keeping a bool around that must be kept in sync with a pointer is not only wasteful of memory, it is an opportunity for bugs. Second, I see no reason why this struct should be mutable. Third, why do you need this struct in the first place? It looks like you are associating a byte ID with a metadata block; are there only 256 possible BlockMetaDatas in the world? Or do a lot of them have the same ID? You can probably find a better data structure that is more space-efficient.

Comment: Fourth, if you *really* want to save memory then allocate *two* arrays: one array of bytes and one array of references. Remember, references have to be word-aligned, and so a struct that contains a reference and a byte uses the same amount of memory as a struct that contains two references.

Comment: I've removed the boolean variable already, I was just worried about the program's performance. The reason why I need this struct is as follows: Imagine a 3D world ("blocks" array in my question). There are a maximum of 255 types of blocks (ID). However, each block can have different meta data. For example, if there are several blocks whose ID is 123 in my world, it would be possible that some of them have meta data, whilst some of them don't. It's basically an object that describes a Block object in a further way *if needed*. But I think I'm a bit overly concerned about performance and memory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off, if you really want to save memory then don't be using a struct or a class.

```
byte[,,] blockTypes = new byte[16, 256, 16]; 
BlockMetaData[,,] blockMetadata = new BlockMetaData[16, 256, 16];
```

You want to *tightly pack similar things together in memory*.  You never want to put a byte next to a reference in a struct if you can possibly avoid it; such a struct will waste three to seven bytes automatically.  **References have to be word-aligned in .NET.**

Second, I'm assuming that you're building a voxel system here. There might be a better way to represent the voxels than a 3-d array, depending on their distribution. If you are going to be making a truly enormous number of these things then store them in an **immutable octree**. By using the *persistence* properties of the immutable octree you can make cubic structures with *quadrillions* of voxels in them so long as the universe you are representing is "clumpy". That is, there are large regions of similarity throughout the world.  You trade somewhat larger O(lg n) time for accessing and changing elements, but you get to have way, way more elements to work with.

Third, "ID" is a really bad way to represent the concept of "type". When I see "ID" I assume that the number uniquely *identifies* the element, not *describes* it. Consider changing the name to something less confusing.

Fourth, how many of the elements have metadata? You can probably do far better than an array of references if the number of elements with metadata is small compared to the total number of elements. Consider a sparse array approach; sparse arrays are much more space efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest I don't really understand much from what you have said (partially because English is not my first language, also because I've never been really good at maths) but I will definitely look into it as it seems very interesting. Thanks again!

Comment: @Eric: Your post is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25862171/993547).

Answer (score 4):

Do they *really* have to be mutable? You could always make it an immutable struct with methods to create a new value with one field different:

```
struct Block
{
    // I'd definitely get rid of the HasMetaData
    private readonly byte id;
    private readonly BlockMetaData metaData;

    public Block(byte id, BlockMetaData metaData)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.metaData = metaData;
    }

    public byte Id { get { return id; } }
    public BlockMetaData MetaData { get { return metaData; } }

    public Block WithId(byte newId)
    {
        return new Block(newId, metaData);
    }

    public Block WithMetaData(BlockMetaData newMetaData)
    {
        return new Block(id, newMetaData);
    }
}
```

I'm still not sure whether I'd make it a struct, to be honest - but I'd try to make it immutable either way, I suspect.

What are your performance *requirements* in terms of both memory and speed? How close does an immutable class come to those requirements?

Comment: Looking at your code, they don't really have to be mutable. The way you put it would work just fine. Thanks for that. My performance requirements are not that big, although I don't like to waste memory on a project like this if it can be done cheaper. I don't raelly understand your second question, I'm sorry, because I also don't really get the point of immutable classes. Wouldn't it be smarter to make types that won't change structs?

Comment: @haiyyu: Nope, that's definitely not the only criterion. Take `string` for example - that's an immutable class, and I'm jolly glad it is. Immutability generally makes for more readable code, and simpler thread safety - when used judiciously, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Immutability can be a good thing, but immutability of a struct instance is determined by the storage location where it is held, not the type of struct.  Saying `structField = new StructType(whatever);` creates a new instance of `StructType` and then *mutates* `structField` so all its fields match those of the new instance.  When the advice to avoid mutable structs was first written, the C# compiler would let one write silly code like `ListOfStructs[4].SomeField = 5`, even though the code wouldn't actually work.  Forbidding such mutations on any instance of the struct was a way...

Comment: @supercat: I don't think there's any point in discussing this on *every answer I give recommending against using mutable structs*. Can't we just agree to disagree and drop it? Going over the same ground time and time again doesn't help anyone.

Comment: ...to make the compiler reject such code (other than changing the compiler, it was probably pretty much the only way).  Since the C# compiler now rejects such code however, however, even when the struct type allows individual fields and properties to be manipulated, there's not really any benefit to forbidding fields to be modified individually in cases where it wouldn't violate any invariants the struct is supposed to maintain.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't think I'd previously mentioned the fact that the C# compiler had changed since the advice was first written.  As to whether that changes the way in which you would view the advice, who knows.  But I thought it an interesting point that I hadn't mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

An array of structs will offer better storage efficiency than an array of immutable references to distinct class instances having the same fields, because the latter will require all of the memory required by the former, in addition to memory to manage the class instances and memory required to hold the references.  All that having been said, your struct as designed has a very inefficient layout.  If you're really concerned about space, and every item in fact needs to independently store a byte, a Boolean, and a class reference, your best bet may be to either have two arrays of byte (a byte is actually smaller than a Boolean) and an array of class references, or else have an array of bytes, an array with 1/32 as many elements of something like BitVector32, and an array of class references.