# What is "word-aligned" in .NET?

Tags: .net, struct

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335999/540345) in this post, [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) told `References have to be word-aligned in .NET`. Could someone please explain what does he mean here? - searched on the internet but couldn't find any helpful resource regarding this.

Here is the full sentence:

> You never want to put a byte next to a reference in a struct if you
>   can possibly avoid it; such a struct will waste three to seven bytes
>   automatically. References have to be word-aligned in .NET.

Comment: The word size is the natural size of the data processed by the CPU. 4 bytes (32 bits) on a 32 bits processor, 8 bytes (64 bits) on a 64 bits processor. So putting a byte before a reference will require 3 or 7 extra padding bytes depending on the underlying processor architecture.

Comment: It simply means that an address of a pointer must be N*sizeof(pointer).

Comment: Strictly they dont have to be, but it will make access to the memory a lot slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with the size of the data and the alignment and padding of it inside the struct.

It is explained [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) (emphasis mine):

> What is important is that the compiler will add “padding” bytes to **align the data within a struct**. You can control the padding explicitly, but notice that some processors throw an exception if you use data that isn’t aligned, and this creates a more complicated problem for .NET Compact users.

Also take a look [here](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_word_size_in_a_computer_processor). Apparently, the word size is

> the number of bits that a CPU can process at one time.

So aligning your data will mean to put them together in that way there is no memory lost between them due to padding and that you take in consideration the size of the memory that can be read on that specific platform.

Comment: Give it some time to let others answer.

Answer (score 1):

Memory on any modern microprocessor is physically and logically subdivided into chunks whose size is a power of two.  In the 1970s the normal chunk size for microprocessor memory systems was 8 bits, though by 1979 some used 16.  Since then, chunk sizes have gotten considerably bigger (1024 bits or more(*)).  In order to guarantee that an attempted memory operation can be performed in a single indivisible step which will either completely succeed or completely fail, its effects must generally be confined to a single memory chunk.  Otherwise, it would be possible for a memory operation which spanned two memory chunks to modify the first, but then prove unable to modify the second, leaving the operation partially completed.

References take 32 bits (four bytes) to store on the x86, and 64 bits (eight bytes) on the x64 platform.  It is absolutely critical that any attempt to write to a reference must either update all of the bits or none of the bits.  Although references could be placed start anywhere within a memory chunk except for the last 3 or 7 bytes and still be accessed atomically, the fact that memory chunk sizes are a multiple of 8 bytes means that any location whose address is a multiple of four is at least four bytes away from the end of its memory chunk, and likewise with multiples of eight.  Thus, requiring that four-byte things' addresses be multiples of four, and eight-byte things' address be multiples of eight will avoid having any single item cross a memory-chunk boundary.

(*) In modern caching and virtual memory systems, memory is made of several nested layers; outer layers often have larger chunk sizes than inner layers.  Some outer layer chunks are much larger than 1024 bits [a paged memory system may map chunks 64K bytes or 524,288 bits], but that doesn't really batter because anything that sits within a single 64-bit chunk will sit within a single 524,288-bit chunk.